# How to add the below time using python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a text string with the following timestamps separated by white space:

```
"""00:03:45.08 00:06:10.07 00:04:55.46 00:04:09.78 00:04:21.08 00:03:40.40 00:05:23.87 00:04:06.54 00:03:37.22 00:04:05.82 00:06:18.77 00:04:59.04 00:02:56.44 00:04:19.76 00:04:47.39 00:03:30.67 00:04:42.27 00:04:18.71 00:04:45.48 00:03:34.84 00:04:06.15 00:04:44,54 00:04:37.37 00:05:23.74 00:06:26,34 00:04:07.06 00:04:56.44"""
```

How can I add up all the timestamps that are in the string?

Comment: could you show what have you tried? you will at least have this values in a list of strings or something? Or are they already in a datetime format?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In 'n' i had the values as str but using date_time_string= n

date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_string, '%H:%M:%S.%f') its now in datetime.datetime

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+add+two+different+times+in+python

Answer (score 0):

I considered the input data to be strings, with space as separator:

```
s = """00:03:45.08 00:06:10.07 00:04:55.46 00:04:09.78 00:04:21.08 00:03:40.40 00:05:23.87 00:04:06.54 00:03:37.22 00:04:05.82 00:06:18.77 00:04:59.04 00:02:56.44 00:04:19.76 00:04:47.39 00:03:30.67 00:04:42.27 00:04:18.71 00:04:45.48 00:03:34.84 00:04:06.15 00:04:44,54 00:04:37.37 00:05:23.74 00:06:26,34 00:04:07.06 00:04:56.44"""
```

This code is for you:

```
import datetime

list_str = s.replace(',','.').split(" ")
list_date = map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), list_str)
str(sum(list_date, datetime.timedelta(0)))
```

Output:

```
'2:02:50.330000'
```

You get the same result using this one-liner:

```
str(sum(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), s.replace(',','.').split(" ")), 
        datetime.timedelta(0)))
```

**Explanation**

First we need to transform the input string into a list of strings:

```
list_str = s.replace(',','.').split(" ")
```

each item in the list is converted to datetime format (the format in which python represents dates) to the format `'%H:%M:%S.%f'` using [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and subtracting the library start date (1900-01-01). I apply the conversion to the entire list using the map function:

```
list_date = map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), list_str)
```

This way I get a list of [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) elements, which I sum using the sum function. I convert the result to string format using the str() function:

```
str(sum(list_date, datetime.timedelta(0)))
```